# tensorflow custom loop does not end in first epoch and progress bar runs to infinite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, progress-bar, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to write a tensorflow custom training loop and include some tensorboard utilities.

Here is the full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pathlib import Path
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
from os import listdir
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import shuffle, choice, uniform

from os.path import isdir, dirname, abspath, join
from os import makedirs
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import (ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard,
                                        EarlyStopping, LearningRateScheduler)

import io
from natsort import natsorted
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential,Model

from tensorflow.keras.applications import (DenseNet201, InceptionV3, MobileNetV2,
                                           ResNet101, Xception, EfficientNetB7,VGG19, NASNetLarge)
from tensorflow.keras.applications import (densenet, inception_v3, mobilenet_v2,
                                           resnet, xception, efficientnet, vgg19, nasnet)

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Rescaling, Resizing
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Progbar


ROOT = '/content/drive/MyDrive'
data_path = 'cropped/'
train_path = data_path + 'train'
val_path = data_path + 'val'

labels = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(listdir(train_path))}

models = {
    'densenet': DenseNet201,
    'xception': Xception,
    'inceptionv3': InceptionV3,
    'effecientnetb7': EfficientNetB7,
    'vgg19': VGG19,
    'nasnetlarge': NASNetLarge,
    'mobilenetv2': MobileNetV2,
    'resnet': ResNet101
}

# models['densenet']()

preprocess_pipeline = {
    'densenet': densenet.preprocess_input,
    'xception': xception.preprocess_input,
    'inceptionv3': inception_v3.preprocess_input,
    'effecientnetb7': efficientnet.preprocess_input,
    'vgg19': vgg19.preprocess_input,
    'nasnetlarge': nasnet.preprocess_input,
    'mobilenetv2': mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input,
    'resnet': resnet.preprocess_input
}


def configure_for_performance(ds, buffer_size, batch_size):
    """
    Configures caching and prefetching
    """
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=buffer_size)
    return ds


def generator(tfrecord_file, batch_size, n_data, validation_ratio, reshuffle_each_iteration=False):
    """
    Returns training and validation generators with infinite repeat.
    """
    reader = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=[tfrecord_file])
    reader.shuffle(n_data, reshuffle_each_iteration=reshuffle_each_iteration)
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

    val_size = int(n_data * validation_ratio)
    train_ds = reader.skip(val_size)
    val_ds = reader.take(val_size)

    # Parsing data from tfrecord format.
    train_ds = train_ds.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    
    # Some data augmentation.
    train_ds = train_ds.map(_augment_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds, AUTOTUNE, batch_size).repeat()

    val_ds = val_ds.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = val_ds.map(_augment_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds, AUTOTUNE, batch_size).repeat() # Is this repeat function the reason behind the issue 
    return train_ds, val_ds

def create_model(optimizer, name='densenet', include_compile=True):
    base_model = models[name](include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.layers[-1].output)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    output = Dense(12, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(base_model.inputs, output)

    if include_compile:
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=optimizer,
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Now let's create a model and initialize:

```
n_data = len(list(Path(data_path).rglob('*.jpg'))) # Find out how many images are there
validation_ratio = 0.2
val_size = int(n_data * validation_ratio) # Find out validation image size.
train_size = n_data - val_size # And train images size
batch_size = 64
n_epochs = 5

# Tfrecord of images
filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/cropped_data.tfrecord'

train_ds, val_ds = generator(filename,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            n_data=n_data,
                            validation_ratio=validation_ratio,
                            reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

# Tensorboard initialization
model_name = 'xception'

path_to_run = "runs/run_1"
tb_train_path = join(path_to_run, 'logs','train')
tb_test_path = join(path_to_run, 'logs', 'test')

train_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(tb_train_path)
test_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(tb_test_path)
train_step = test_step = 0

blocks_to_train = []
lr = 1e-4

optimizer = SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6,momentum=0.9,nesterov=True)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
acc_metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy()

# Create the xception model
model = create_model(optimizer, name=model_name, include_compile=False)

metrics = {'acc': 0.0, 'loss': 0.0, 'val_acc': 0.0, 'val_loss': 0.0, 'lr': lr}
```

And this is the loop for training and testing:

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    # Iterate through the training set
    progress_bar = Progbar(train_size, stateful_metrics=list(metrics.keys()))

    for batch_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(train_ds):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = model(x, training=True)
            loss = loss_fn(y, y_pred)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
        acc_metric.update_state(y, y_pred)
        train_step += 1
        progress_bar.update(batch_idx*batch_size, values=[('acc',acc_metric.result()),
                                       ('loss', loss)])

    with train_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar("Loss", loss, step=epoch)
        tf.summary.scalar(
            "Accuracy", acc_metric.result(), step=epoch
        )

    # reset accuracy between epochs (and for testing and test)

    acc_metric.reset_states()


    for batch_idx, (x,y) in enumerate(val_ds):
        y_pred = model(x, training=False)
        loss = loss_fn(y, y_pred)
        acc_metric.update_state(y,
                                y_pred)
        confusion += get_confusion_matrix(y, y_pred, class_names=list(labels.keys()))

    with test_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar("Loss", loss, step=epoch)
        tf.summary.scalar("Accuracy", acc_metric.result(), step=epoch)

    progress_bar.update(train_size, values=[('val_acc', acc_metric.result()), ('val_loss', loss)])

    # reset accuracy between epochs (and for testing and test)
    acc_metric.reset_states()
```

I modified the code and removed some of tensorboard utilities. The code starts training but it does not stop in the end of predefined epochs. I see the progress bar keeps going and never stops to show the validation metrics.

Can you guys help me to have the exact same progress bar like `keras.fit` function.

Thanks

Comment: For progress bar, a simple change would be to use `tqdm`'s  `trange` instead of range. https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: My main problem is the matter that the data generator does not end in training section and does not start the validation part.

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam Hi, which dataset you used? even though you posted your solution, I am interested in reproducing it.

Comment: @Jared  this is the link to what I have done recently. but the code is not flawless yet. https://github.com/masouduut94/digikala-color-classification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the (silly) reason behind the long training epoch:

Data consists of `train_size` training data and `val_size` validation data without considering batches. for example, training data consists of 4886 data samples which would be 76 data batches (with `batch_size=64`).

when I use `for batch_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(train_gen):`, I have a total number of 76 batches but I loop through 4886 batches in the loop by mistake.

I rewrote the following lines to these:

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
# Iterate through the training set
progress_bar = Progbar(train_size, stateful_metrics=list(metrics.keys()))

train_gen = train_ds.take(train_size//batch_size) # This line

for batch_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(train_gen):

.....


val_gen = val_ds.take(val_size//batch_size)

for batch_idx, (x,y) in enumerate(val_gen):
```